# How to check if int occurs in list 3 times?

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, integer

I have a list that contains ints, all from 0-2. Now I have to check if any of these numbers occurs exactly 3 times. How would one check that?

Example:

```
{ 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 } //this is true

{ 1, 1, 2, 0, 0 } //this is false

{ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 } //this is true
```

Comment: Is Java, Dart, C++ (any of them) implementation ok

Comment: @Jasurbek I'm using c#

Comment: habe you tried using an oldscool loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use LINQ for this:

```
bool containsNum3x = 
    list
        .GroupBy(i => i) // group the 0s into a subset, the 1s into a subset, etc
        .Any(s => s.Count()  == 3); // check if the size of any subset is exactly 3
```

Docs:

- [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1)
- [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netcore-3.1)

You might need to add `using System.Linq` in order at the top of your code file.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use a dictionary for this. Time Complexity O(N) Space Complexity O(N)

```
static void countFreq(List<int> ls)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(ls[i]))
        {
            dict[ls[i]] =  dict[ls[i]]+ 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(ls[i], 1);
        }
    }

            
    for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(ls[i]) && dict[ls[i]] != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ls[i] + " " + dict[ls[i]]);
            dict[ls[i]] = -1;
        }
    }
}

            
    for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(ls[i]) && dict[ls[i]] != -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ls[i] + " " + dict[ls[i]]);
            dict.Remove(ls[i]);
            dict.Add(ls[i], -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool containsIntNTimes (List<int> intList, int lookFor, int amount)
{
    foreach(int i in intList)
    {
        if(i == lookFor)
            amount--;

        if (amount == 0)
            return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}


containsIntNTimes(myIntList, 0, 3);
containsIntNTimes(myIntList, 1, 3);
containsIntNTimes(myIntList, 2, 3);
```